# Рандом в двумерном квадратном массиве

Tags: c++, случайные-числа, олимпиада, соревнование

Как заполнить массив рандомно только 0, 1 и 3, не взяв при этом 2.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Бенефис троечки: `a[i][j] = (3 + rand()%3) & 3;`

Comment: @MBo Дайте ответом, на плюсик тянет :)

Comment: Вот так случайно и получаются соревнования :) Интересно, как ТС будет выбирать, чей ответ принять - все хороши.

Answer (score 13):

В начале были такие варианты:

```
a[i][j] = -3 ^ (rand() % 3 - 4);
```

и

```
a[i][j] = (1 - rand() % 3) & 3;
```

Но потом нашел более быстрый способ со сдвигом (всего 2 операции):

```
a[i][j] = 3 >> (rand() % 3);
```

Можно конечно и следующим способом попробовать, но случаев, когда выпадают нули, возможно, будет больше:

```
a[i][j] = 3 >> (rand() & 3);
```

Comment: Хоть способ с массивом, на мой взгляд, самый универсальный/наглядный,  но вариант `3 >> (rand() % 3)` определённо впечатляет :) За счёт приоритета операций можно ещё и скобки убрать: `3 >> rand() % 3`.

Comment: @wololo, действительно, без скобок тоже работает :)

Comment: Отличная находка с `3 >>`

Answer (score 11):

Ну типа

```
int val[3] = {0,1,3};
for(int i = 0; i < строк; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < столбцов; ++j)
        a[i][j] = val[rand()%3];
```

или, без массива:

```
for(int i = 0; i < строк; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < столбцов; ++j)
    {
        int n = rand()%3;
        a[i][j] = n*(n+1)/2;
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

как вариант:

1. создаете массив

   ```
    const int arr[] = {0, 1, 3}
   ```
2. получаете случайное число от 0 до 2 включительно:

   ```
    const int pos = rand() % 3;
   ```
3. получаете нужное значение:

   ```
    const int value = arr[pos];
   ```

так вы получите равномерное распределение между данными числами, причем можно использовать любые последовательности чисел и т.д. - т.е. более универсальное даже решение, чем вы требуете

Answer (score 10):

Присваивать исключив двойку:

```
arr[i][j] = (rand() % 3 + 1) ^ 2;
```

Comment: Классное решение :)

Comment: @Harry, спасибо, но я поленился объяснять, почему эта задача решается таким способом, если вместо тройки будет любое число вида `4n - 1`

Comment: Как ни странно, такая простая задача - и такие интересные решения (ваше, @MBo)... Интересно, еще кто-то какое-то нетривиальное преобразование предложит?

Answer (score 10):

На арене только тройки:

```
a[i][j] = (3 + rand()%3) & 3;
```

преобразуем диапазон `0..2` в `3..5` и оставляем только два младших бита

Comment: можно `(rand() % 3 - 1) & 0x3;`

Comment: Да, тоже вариант хороший (но констант больше ;))

Comment: Может там декремент задействуется ))

Answer (score 4):

Такого варианта, вроде, не было еще (хотя, это самое первое что пришло мне в голову при чтении вопроса):

```
int n = rand() % 3;
a[i][j] = n == 2 ? 3 : n;
```

Comment: можно `a[i][j] = n + n >> 1;`

Comment: @TigerTV.ru, опубликуйте отдельным ответом, похоже такого варианта еще не было

Answer (score 3):

Еще вариант с дополнительной переменной:

```cpp
int n = rand() % 3;
a[i][j] = n + (n >> 1);
```

или

```cpp
a[i][j] = 3 * (rand() % 3) / 2;
```

или

```cpp
a[i][j] = rand() % 3 * 3 % 5;
```

или

```cpp
a[i][j] = rand() % 3 * 5 / 3;
```

или

```cpp
a[i][j] = (10 >> rand() % 3) / 3;
```

Comment: Прикольно, вариантов, основанных на целочисленном делении, ещё, похоже, не было

Comment: @АндрейNOP, да, наверное еще можно нагенерировать )