# Заполнение квадратного массива

Tags: c++

Мне нужно заполнить массив 0, 1 и 3 рандомно выше главной диагонали, на место главной диагонали записать нули, а ниже главной диагонали сделать зеркальное отображение того, что выше, но как-то не выходит у меня.

```
    //Заполнение верхней части массива 0,1 или 3.
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
        if (j>i) {
        a[i][j] = (3 + rand()%3) & 3;
        }
    }
    }
//Симметричное заполнение нижней части, обнудение главной диагонали
for (i=0;i<n;++i) {
        for (j=0;j<n;j++) {
                if (j<i) {
                    a[i][j]=3-a[j][i];
                }
                if (i==j) {
                    a[i][j]=0;
                }
                cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
        }
```

Comment: Вы ещё не закончили с предыдущими вопросами, а уже новый задаёте.

Answer (score 4):

Что-то типа

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    for (j = i; j < n; ++j)
    {
        a[i][j] = a[j][i] = (i==j) ? 0 : (3 + rand()%3) & 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, а где у вас возникли сложности с пониманием кода? :)

Comment: ответ с кодом и объяснением лучше ответа с кодом без объяснения. это соображение представляется мне довольно очевидным, но если у вас есть сомнения по этому поводу, стоит обсудить их на мете.

Comment: Ну так-то [бенефис троечки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1232181) вполне может озадачить неподготовленного читателя ;)

Comment: @wololo Бенефис троечки - у ТС в вопросе...

Answer (score 1):

Заполняем главную диагональ массива нулем, а также [числами 0, 1 и 3 рандомно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1232400/281034) выше и ниже главной диагонали с зеркалированием одновременно.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    a[i][i] = 0;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
        a[i][j] = a[j][i] = 3 >> rand() % 3;
    }
}
```

PS. [Часть кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1232405/281034) я взял у @Harry